# MySql query to fetch excel cell positions stored in db table in order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that has cell data and the corresponding position. I want to display an html table using PHP where the data in the "cell data" column in the database is positioned as given in the "cell position" column of the the same record. How am I going to do this. Is it possible to do it fetch the data as such in mysql solely? If not any points on achieving this would be most welcome.

The excel format is used to stored the cell position.

```
                 Cell Data     Cell Position
                  Hello             A1
                  Bello             C2
```

**EDIT**
   I welcome programming solution if not solely with mysql. But I don't want any libraries I know I can do this with PHPExcel...

Comment: Do columns go above Z, ie AA, AB, etc?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes it goes

Comment: it's a programming question clearly how come it got closing votes....so, would a question with difficulty gets closed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was simply columns A-Z, then this is a simple answer

```
SELECT celldata,
       SUBSTR(cellposition,1,2) AS column,
       SUBSTR(cellposition,2) AS row,
       cellposition
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY 3,2
```

It gets a bit harder when you might have additional columns like 'AA', 'AZ', 'BA', etc... not just to extract the column/row; but also to handle the column ordering... I'm still working on a solution for that.
Without actually writing it all out, I'd do a CASE test on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th characters of cellposition testing for a numeric value, and adjust the SUBSTR offset and length accordingly to split the row and column components, and then use LPAD() to pad the column with spaces to 3 characters length.

If you can extend your MySQL, then [LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) provides additional PREG_CAPTURE and PREG_POSITION functions in MySQL that would make this a lot easier; but you need to recompile MySQL from source to do this. The MySQL developers really should consider implementing this as standard.

It's actually a lot easier in PHP as you can simply retrieve the records in any order, then usort() in PHP and handle the splitting there using something like:

```
list($c,$r) = sscanf($coord,'%[A-Z]%d');
$c = str_pad($c, 3, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

to split row/col and adjust col to a comparable string by padding it; but that could be painfully memory-expensive if you're working with large volumes of data.

I used an array keyed on the cell address, and with the value as the cell value, so:

```
function cellAddressCompare($a, $b)
{
    sscanf($a,'%[A-Z]%d', $ac, $ar);
    sscanf($b,'%[A-Z]%d', $bc, $br);

    if ($ar == $br) {
        return strcasecmp(strlen($ac) . $ac, strlen($bc) . $bc);
    }
    return ($ar < $br) ? -1 : 1;
}

uksort ($testArray, 'cellAddressCompare');
```

Comment: +1, salute to your answer and you :) please consider adding good ideas on this topic here in future

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use this library, it's really nice, quick and easy to use:

http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/

Put this in a loop which gets the cell position from the database:

```
 use SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel;

 $excel = new SimpleExcel('CSV');
 $excel->loadFile('/home/faisalman/Downloads/test.csv', 'CSV')

 echo print_r($excel->getWorksheet(1)->getCell($mysql_Cpos, $mysql_Rpos));
```

if you want to use the MySQL soley you can previously import your excel file to a mysql database using http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ as described here:

http://major.io/2008/11/07/importing-excel-files-into-mysql-with-php/

then you can handle it as usual!

Comment: do you want to display the data in the excel file? or in the database? because your question isn't clear at all...

Comment: I have update my question... I waant to display the cell values of first column of my db table with respect to the positions given in second column. the cell positions are in excel cell positions like A1,B1 etc... and I want a programmatic solution than libraries like PHPExcel